# Can't install PHP on bullseye Debian

Tags: php, debian, bullseye

> apt install php7.3 php7.3-common php7.3-cli

It returns this error:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state
> information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This may
> mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are
> using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not
> yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following
> information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  php-common : Breaks:
> php7.3-common but 7.3.15-3 is to be installed  php7.3 : Depends:
> libapache2-mod-php7.3 but it is not installable or
> php7.3-fpm but it is not installable or
> php7.3-cgi but it is not installable  php7.3-cli : Depends: php7.3-json but it is not installable E: Unable to correct
> problems, you have held broken packages.

And when I try to install:

> apt install php7.3-fpm

I have:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state
> information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This may
> mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are
> using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not
> yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following
> information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  php-common : Breaks:
> php7.3-common but 7.3.15-3 is to be installed E: Unable to correct
> problems, you have held broken packages.

That's my source.list:

```
# Debian 11 (bullseye)
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main

# Aggiornamenti di sicurezza per bullseye
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main

# Aggiornamenti raccomandati per bullseye (abilitati solo dal rilascio in poi)
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye-updates main
```

My system is a dist-upgrade from Buster.  I cant figure out whats wrong.

#### UPDATE

it says: Reading package lists... Done E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye/updates Release' does not have a Release file. N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Answer (score 3):

The `deb-src` lines in your sources.list are used to download only the [sources package](https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging/SourcePackage), a regular `sources.list` should contain the lines starting with `deb` , here is a good explanation from debian wiki:

> ## [Archive type](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Archive_type)
>
> The first word on each line, deb or deb-src, indicates the type of archive. Deb indicates that the archive contains binary packages (deb), the pre-compiled packages that we normally use. Deb-src indicates source packages, which are the original program sources plus the Debian control file (.dsc) and the diff.gz containing the changes needed for packaging the program.

To solve the problem ,you need to adjust the content of your `sources.list` as follows ([see sources.list example](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Example_sources.list)):

```
sudo apt edit-sources
```

Then past the following lines:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
```

Install [php*](https://wiki.debian.org/PHP):

```
sudo apt install php7.3 php7.3-common php7.3-cli
```

Comment: It says:
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: @Isabelle I have edited my answer (see the sources.list).

Answer (score 1):

Install package dependencies

php7.3-common

trace them manually or try `gdebi`(`apt install gdebi`), it will fetch dependencies of apt packages.

Also unless you are testing release (bullseye) not recommended to install.

Comment: it says  


The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php-common : Breaks: php7.3-common but 7.3.15-3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: thank you, i solved without installing gdebi following GAD3R hints